# Socket server using servlets

Tags: java, sockets, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am about to make an application that needs to have a web interface for users to interact with and a low level UDP message interface with some existing applications.  Is it possible for a java servlet based application to provide both a web interface and at the same time act as a UDP socket server.

Both the interfaces are actually independent,  the UDP interface is for receiving messages which shall be logged to a database,  while the web interface is merely for viewing data from that database.  I do not require any data to be pushed to the web interface asynchronously.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting up multiple web services using the same servlet context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23355560/setting-up-multiple-web-services-using-the-same-servlet-context)

Comment: I'm assuming that the UDP interface is asynchronous.  This makes interacting with a webpage difficult.  There are AJAX methods to have a browser update information, but there is not really a standard for having a server provide information asynchronously to a web browser.  I don't think a servlet makes sense for this purpose, but I leave it as a comment because I'm not sure.

Comment: Nope, thats not possible! What you have to do, is manage your socket server by your own, may be using ThreadPoolExecutor.

Comment: @Jared I do not require any asynchronous data to be pushed to the web interface.  I have edited the question to that effect.

Comment: @drum There is nothing in this question about multiple web services.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible. You can do it the spring way by using a `ServletContextListener` :

- you start your UDP server in an independant thread when receiving `contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)`
- you stop it (and clean all around) when receiving `contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)`

That way, your UDP service is aware of the servlet context and can share some information via the servlets through it.

But if the only interface between the 2 parts is the database, you can also have two independant applications in a KISS attitude ...

Comment: As you suggested,  having two applications is one way of doing it,  but I was thinking that the KISS principle would suggest merging both into a single service.

Comment: @Ajoy : It depends how much proficiency you have on both side. IMHO it is easyer for a little experienced programmer to write two independant apps as each will be smaller and simpler. But it will be more efficient to have one single app in terms of computer resources, code duplication and maintainability (bug fixing or evolutions).